Splitting a text string into a list of dictionaries
I start out with this little ditty, but would need to clean it up, create key-value pairs and for each customer, create their own dictionary part of a list of customer dictonaries.
service_notes = ['Customer AliceJenkins\n',
 'Car Honda\n',
 'Service Fifty_Thousand\n','Customer BobElliot\n',
 'Car Toyota, Rav4, Silver, 2018\n',
 'Service Thirty_Thousand,\n',
 'Customer CharlieWallace\n',
 'Car Ford\n',
 'Service Ten_Thousand\n']


Firstly, I cleaned up the listed string with overthinking by creating a delimited between would-be key-value pairs, but ran into difficulty in the Car Toyota section) and finally removed the line change.
then when I tried to split the values into key-value pairs, i got an error for using str split functions on a list. so made the list into a str... and well yeah. didnt work.

data_arr = [entry.replace(" ", ": ").replace(",:", " ").replace("\n","") for entry in service_notes]
data_arr = str(data_arr)
sep = ': '
lst = data_arr.split(sep)
d = dict(zip(lst[0::2], lst[1::2]))
print(d)


end results is not a useable dictionary. nor could i create dictionaries for each customer entry.
{"['Customer": "AliceJenkins', 'Car", "Honda', 'Service": "Fifty_Thousand', 'Customer", "BobElliot', 'Car": "Totota  Rav4  Silver  2018', 'Service", "Thirty_Thousand,', 'Customer": "CharlieWallace', 'Car", "Ford', 'Service": "Ten_Thousand']"}


What would be a "usable dictionary"?

Where "Customer", "Car", and "Service" are singular keys followed by a value. Right now, for the key "Customer" the value is AliceJenkins, Car .... not sure why

And you would want to end up with a list of such dictionaries, one dictionary for each 3 consecutive items in the original list?

this would be the ideal result - a list of dictionaries as follows:   [{'Customer': 'AliceJenkins', 'Car': 'Honda', 'Service': 'Fifty_Thousand'},
{'Customer': 'BobElliot', 'Car': 'Totota Rav4 Silver 2018', 'Service': 'Thirty_Thousand,'},
{'Customer': 'CharlieWallace', 'Car': 'Ford', 'Service': 'Ten_Thousand'}]

Here you go:
# Remove the commas & trailing space(s), then split on the first space for each item
data_arr = [entry.replace(",","").strip().split(" ",1) for entry in service_notes]

# Create a list of dictionaries, each made from 3 consecutive elements of data_arr
dict_arr = [dict(datum) for datum in zip(data_arr[0::3], data_arr[1::3], data_arr[2::3])]


the solution seems so clear. I do need to read up on using dict() and zip(). Many thanks! I'm also taken note how you mapped out the steps.

Assuming there are consistently 3 fields per customer, here’s a one-liner that will work if you’re on python 3.12 or newer (for the itertools.batched function):
from itertools import batched

d = [dict(b) for b in batched((a.strip('\n').split(maxsplit=1) for a in service_notes), 3)]

If you’re not on python 3.12, you can define your own batched function (copied from the itertools documentation):
from itertools import islice

def batched(iterable, n, *, strict=False):
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError('n must be at least one')
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    while batch := tuple(islice(iterator, n)):
        if strict and len(batch) != n:
            raise ValueError('batched(): incomplete batch')
        yield batch

It doesn’t strip out the commas, but it would be trivial to add that if you need to.

I'll say that unless participating in a coding golf competition, one-liners are almost never good examples of maintainable code. There's nothing wrong in splitting up a gigantic list comprehension for legibility.

With no hard-coding of any specific key or the number of keys per record, a more generic approach is to check if the current key already exists in the last record, in which case add a new record before updating the record with the new key-value pair:
records = []
for note in service_notes:
    key, _, value = note.partition(' ')
    if not records or key in records[-1]:
        records.append({})
    records[-1][key] = value.rstrip(',\n')

records becomes:
[{'Customer': 'AliceJenkins', 'Car': 'Honda', 'Service': 'Fifty_Thousand'}, {'Customer': 'BobElliot', 'Car': 'Toyota, Rav4, Silver, 2018', 'Service': 'Thirty_Thousand'}, {'Customer': 'CharlieWallace', 'Car': 'Ford', 'Service': 'Ten_Thousand'}]

Demo here

service_notes = ['Customer AliceJenkins\n',
 'Car Honda\n',
 'Service Fifty_Thousand\n', 'Customer BobElliot\n',
 'Car Toyota, Rav4, Silver, 2018\n',
 'Service Thirty_Thousand,\n',
 'Customer CharlieWallace\n',
 'Car Ford\n',
 'Service Ten_Thousand\n']

customers = []

for word in service_notes:
    tokens = word.split(maxsplit=1)
    entry = {tokens[0]: tokens[1].strip()}
    if tokens[0] == "Customer":
        customers.append(entry)
    else:
        customers[-1].update(entry)

print(customers)

Output:
[
    {'Customer': 'AliceJenkins', 'Car': 'Honda', 'Service': 'Fifty_Thousand'},
    {'Customer': 'BobElliot', 'Car': 'Toyota, Rav4, Silver, 2018', 'Service': 'Thirty_Thousand,'},
    {'Customer': 'CharlieWallace', 'Car': 'Ford', 'Service': 'Ten_Thousand'}
]

